# Comparing similar strings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, validation, redundancy

How do I compare similar strings in jquery?

```
<script src="../../js/jq.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    var str1 = $.trim($('#str1').val().toUpperCase());
    var str2 = $.trim($('#str2').val().toUpperCase());
    if(str1==str2){
        console.log('yep');
    }
});
</script>
<input type="text" id="str1" value="One String"/>
<input type="text" id="str2" value="One String1"/>
```

Comparing "One String" and "One String1" is not going to work if I'm only checking if the two values are equal. Is there any way to do this in jquery? For example I only want to compare 90% of the string.

Comment: Can you go into further detail as to how you want the strings compared?

Comment: What do you mean "90% of the string"? That 90% of the characters are equal? Or perhaps that one is a substring of another?

Comment: You could use `str2.indexOf(str1) > -1` if you just wanted to check that `str2` contains `str1`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I want to determine if the pattern of the first string is similar with the other. 90% of the characters might also work, I just want to reduce redundancy of data using jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/Sj5dE/ You can comment out a,b block to see the similitude of the strings. It's of course case-sensitive. I hope this helps. Since your example talked about comparing two similar strings, I thought it'd be most likely that the beginning of the strings are the same so I didn't introduce any substring logic but feel free to change the function.

Answer (score 6):

You can see if one is contained inside the other for example:

```
if (str1.indexOf(str2) >= 0 || str2.indexOf(str1) >= 0)
    console.log('yep');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this it might work

```
    <script src="../../js/jq.js"></script> <script> 
$(function(){     
var str1 = $.trim($('#str1').val().toUpperCase());     
var str2 = $.trim($('#str2').val().toUpperCase());     
if(str1===str2){         console.log('yep');     } }); 
</script> 
<input type="text" id="str1" value="One String"/> 
<input type="text" id="str2" value="One String1"/>
```

Comment: ive been wondering this for some time. I know `=` is for defining, `==` is used to check if its equal, `!=` is not equal but what is `===`? Couldnt find it on google last time lol

Comment: === is strict equality. 5==="5" will result false. Normally, it's possible to get away with type casting but if you want your values to have an exact data type as well as the value then you can use ===. This might help http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 1):

In *javascript* you can use the [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) to get the 90% of the string you would like to compare.

```
$(function(){
    var str1 = $.trim($('#str1').val().toUpperCase().substring(0, 10);
    var str2 = $.trim($('#str2').val().toUpperCase().substring(0, 10);
    if(str1==str2){
        console.log('yep');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

look on

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

the demo in

http://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the string is present or not by

$(".className").replace(/(^|\s)yourTextHere\S+/g, " ");